# uninitialized constant API::V1::MusicController

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rubygems

I'm really sorry to ask this when there are a lot of similar posts but none seams to work for me.

/app/controllers/api/v1/musics_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::MusicsController < ApplicationController::API
  def index
    music = Music.order('created_at DESC');
    render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message:'Loaded articles', data:music},status: :ok
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :music
    end
  end 
end
```

Error:

> activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:271:in
>   `const_get' activesupport (5.1.2)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:271:in`block in constantize'
>   activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in
>   `each' activesupport (5.1.2)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in`inject' activesupport
>   (5.1.2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
>   actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:82:in`
>   controller_class' actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `controller' actionpack
>   (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in`serve'
>   actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in `block
>   in serve' actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in`each' actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve' actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:832:in`call' rack (2.0.3)
>   lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call' rack (2.0.3)
>   lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in`call' rack (2.0.3)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call' rack (2.0.3)
>   lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in`context' rack (2.0.3)
>   lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call' actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in`call' activerecord
>   (5.1.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call' actionpack
>   (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in`block in
>   call' activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in`call' actionpack
>   (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
>   actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in`call'
>   actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
>   railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in`call_app' railties
>   (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call' activesupport
>   (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in
>   `tagged' activesupport (5.1.2)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in`tagged' railties (5.1.2)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call' actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in`call' actionpack
>   (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call' rack
>   (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in`call' rack (2.0.3)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call' activesupport (5.1.2)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in`
>   call' actionpack (5.1.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call' actionpack
>   (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in`call' rack
>   (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call' railties (5.1.2)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in`call' puma (3.9.1)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call' puma (3.9.1)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:602:in`handle_request' puma (3.9.1)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client' puma (3.9.1)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:299:in`block in run' puma (3.9.1)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

Comment: Is it `Music` or `Musics`?

Comment: Is it API or Api?

Comment: I know its wierd but it is Musics

Comment: Could you add the rails server error you're getting?

Comment: `resources :music` for `MusicController`; 


`resources :musics` for `MusicsController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: to change your resources to the plural way `:musics` (which is recommended) or to change the name of your controller and all the files related (routes, directories, controller class) to the singular way.

In the code you've provided you need to specify your `resources` route in the plural way, that's why Rails says it doesn't find the `API::V1::MusicController`, because your controller is called `MusicsController`, try just adding the missing `s` to your route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :musics
    end
  end 
end
```